# Error Message: "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application, IM014."

Tags: visual-studio-2015, odbc, ssas-tabular

I'm running into an issue trying to import data into a Visual Studio Tabular Project using an ODBC connection.  This is my first time putting together a tabular model.

I'm using the "Import from Data Source" wizard.  I can get all the way through the wizard successfully and choose my tables to import.  When I test the connection to the data source, it is successful.  However, on the last step to import the data, I get this error message:

> OLE DB or ODBC error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application; IM014.
>
> A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'e13e1ea2-2c94-4a1f-9b52-4e31d79bb8bf', Name of 'Custom'.

I'm on a 64-bit server but running Visual Studio 2015, which is a 32-bit program as I understand it.

I've configured my ODBC connection using the 32-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator.  I've also set up the Visual Studio project's platform to be x86 instead of the default of "Any CPU."

What am I missing here?  Thank you!